# Parse nested array in JSON Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to parse the 'audience' array.

```
 String data =   {
  "meta":{
    "requests":31454,
    "timestamp":1456706180,
    "status":200,
    "message":"Request successful",
    "method_id":1129,
    "method":{

    }
  },
  "data":[
    {
      "id":3681,
      "employer":"Google",
      "date":"2016-01-05",
      "day":"January",
      "start_time":"17:00",
      "end_time":"19:00",
      "description":"Info session to discuss options at Google for majors outside of Computer Science.",
      "website":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/careers\/students",
      "building":{
        "code":"FED",
        "name":"Federation Hall",
        "room":"Main Hall",
        "latitude":43.4732,
        "longitude":-80.5485,
        "map_url":"https:\/\/uwaterloo.ca\/map\/FED?basemap=D#map=17\/43.4732\/-80.5485"
      },
      "audience":[
        "ENG - Computer",
        "ENG - Electrical",
        "ENG - Mechatronics",
        "ENG - Software",
        "ENG - System Design",
        "MATH - Combinatorics & Optimization",
        "MATH - Computer Science",
        "MATH - Pure Mathematics"
      ],
      "link":"http:\/\/www.ceca.uwaterloo.ca\/students\/hiresessions_details.php?id=3681"
    } 
      }
```

I started with

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray data2 = new JSONArray(obj);
```

But I am unsure how to get the "audience" data now? I tried to create another array from data2, but that gave an error, so I really am not sure how to proceed?

Comment: Explain the downvote. Thats just stupid

Comment: Downvotes arent stupid. Leaving out maybe an error that you are getting would be. And so would not reading [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Good start with

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data);
```

Then, that's an object that you need to *get* the `"data"` array out of, not make a `new` array from that object.

```
JSONArray data = obj.getJsonArray("data");
```

Once you have an array, you can iterate over that with a regular for loop, up to `i < data.length()`.

As you iterate that array, you have more JSON objects that you need to get

```
JSONObject inner = data.getJSONObject(i);
```

And those have the audience array.

```
JSONArray audience = inner.getJSONArray("audience");
```

---

Feel free to [use this site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) and Gson or Jackson libraries to aid your parsing efforts